# How to create a GPO registry item without automatically replacing variables?

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy

I created a registry item in a GPO of REG_EXPAND_SZ type with value "%userprofile%\Shares". The problem is, when the GPO is aplied, the value is created with the data "C:\Users\Default\Shares". Is there a way to mantain the value "%userprofile%\Shares" without automatically replacing the variable inside it?

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

`"%<userprofile>%\Shares"`

Comment: Nice! FYI, I referred to [this TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/252bbf22-bfe6-498d-b0aa-a054f8e4433d/group-policy-preferences-environmental-variables-in-registry-item?forum=w7itproinstall) link.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here https://sdmsoftware.com/forums/topic/escaping-env-variable-while-using-gpp/

You can insert <> between the variable name to prevent auto resolution, so instead of using %userprofile%, I used %<userprofile>% and it worked!